# CloudKit - Saving record progress doesn't perform as expected

Tags: ios, swift3, cloudkit, ckmodifyrecordsoperation

I've a function that saves a record with an image to CloudKit.

Everything works as expected and the records are saved and fetched without issues.

I want to display the upload progress for better UX but when I'm printing the progress in my `operation.perRecordProgressBlock {}` the output comes like

`0.0
0.097003
0.990101
1.0`

So the progress goes from 0.1% to 99% straight.

I expected something like 10%, 20% and so on...

The save record code used is the following:

```
func savePost(_ xrecord: CKRecord) {
    let publicData = CKContainer.default().publicCloudDatabase
    let record: [CKRecord] = [xrecord] // array with a single object
    let saveOperation = CKModifyRecordsOperation.init(recordsToSave: record, recordIDsToDelete: nil)

    saveOperation.perRecordProgressBlock = {(_, progress) -> Void in
        print("\(Float(progress))") 
    }
    saveOperation.perRecordCompletionBlock = {(record, error) -> Void in
        print("completed...")
    }
    publicData.add(saveOperation)
}
```

Is that any way to keep the progress "smooth"? Like using a completionHandler somehow?

Tips are welcome.

Thanks :D

Comment: How big is the record you are saving?  Unless it is very large I wouldn't expect that you will get many progress updates; the network operation won't take very long and there won't be that many packets sent

Comment: Well, for this exact test I'm uploading a attributed string and a photo image.